# “I’ll get right on it”

Tags: meaning, grammar, expressions, slang, conversation

What does it mean to say ( I’ll get right on it) if someone in a really terrible situation and being offered a help and he replied ( I ‘ll get right on it )

Comment: "I'll get right on it" is a sarcastic way of saying "I'm not going to do it."

Comment: Maybe he is on a rooftop during a flood, and someone is inviting him to get on a boat.

Comment: @Robusto If said sarcastically, yes. Just like any other phrase, it's possible to say this sarcastically or not, with opposite intended meanings. The phrase itself isn't inherently sarcastic, though.

Comment: @Nuclear: Yeah, but it's overwhelmingly used sarcastically, so much so that to use it straight is avoided by people who don't want to be misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

I'll get right on it is simply a way to say "I will do that as soon as possible." It just means that one will do a particular task promptly.

In your situation, if someone asked for help and someone said, "I'll get right on it." It means that they will try to get help as soon as possible for the person.

Also check https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ if you're confused on these idioms.